# What do I do instead of grep'ing the output of ps?

Tags: shell, grep, shortcut, idioms, ps

Everyone knows how annoying this is:

```
[mybox:~ #] ps aux | grep myservice
root      2273  0.0  0.0   4360   760 ?        Ss   18:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/myservice
root     18590  0.0  0.0   4100   788 pts/2    S+   21:21   0:00 grep myservice
```

you get the processes you were looking for, plus the grep. So, ok you could do:

```
[mybox:~ #] ps aux | grep myservice | grep -v grep
root      2273  0.0  0.0   4360   760 ?        Ss   18:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/myservice
```

or

```
[mybox:~ #] pgrep myservice
2273
```

but the former is 3 whole commands, and the latter only gets you the process id. Is there some nicer alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you now the full name of the process

```
ps -F -C myservice
```

But it wouldn't work with `myserv` of `'myserv*'`

If you know only a partial one, you can reduce your commands to 2:

```
ps aux | grep [m]yserv
```

Comment: `-p $(pgrep myserv)` instead of `-C myservice`

Comment: I though the idea was to reduce commands, that would still be 2.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing the piped commands into a small bash shell that takes a positional parameter? This would reduce keystrokes if that is the goal.

```
[mybox:~ #] cat mycmd
    #!/bin/bash
    ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep
```

Which could be called:

```
[mybox:~ #] mycmd myservice
  root      2273  0.0  0.0   4360   760 ?        Ss   18:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/myservice
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but: 1. If you do that, you have to remember another shell command 2. If it's not your system, and you don't have a personal account there, leaving executable scripts around is not polite. Got you an upvote though...

Answer (score 1):

`ps` + `pgrep` maybe?

```
$ ps -fp $(pgrep myservice)
UID    PID  PPID  C STIME TTY  TIME      CMD
user   5422  5315  0 15:37 ?   00:00:04  /usr/bin/myservice
```

Comment: This results in an error if the process is not running.

Comment: That's true. You always can redirect errors, to avoid noise (`2> /dev/null`), or save the `pgrep`'s output in a variable, for checking it before `ps`.